# How to Host Gulp based AngularJS MVC application in IIs Server

Tags: angularjs, iis, model-view-controller, deployment, gulp

I have a Web Application in asp.net MVC, but here I didn't add any controller and view, instead of that I have added HTML pages, and AngularJS with Gulpfile.js, now I want to host this application on IIS server: can I do it? If it's not possible then can you give me an idea or hint to deploy this application on any server, please?

Regards,
Vinit Patel

Comment: whe you use the gulp build,what does it generate ? am guessing index.html and bunch of js files(or app.min.js) ? is that right? what do you use asp.net mvc for ? do you have the rest APIs which the angular app is calling implemented in the asp.net mvc ?

Comment: @RohithRajan no in this application no, it's separate application, i had make this application in visual studion and yes when we build it's create all listed files, so have you idea how to deploy this on iis or other web server?